# Check whether a constructor calls another constructor

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor, cil, constructor-chaining

During reflection, is it possible in C# to check whether one constructor calls another?

```
class Test
{
    public Test() : this( false ) { }
    public Test( bool inner ) { }    
}
```

I would like to determine for each [`ConstructorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.constructorinfo.aspx) whether or not it's at the end of chain of invocation.

Comment: Why do you need to do that? The call to the other constructor is compiled as a normal method call, so I think you would need to read the IL of the method to do this.

Comment: @svick I'm [applying aspects](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/), and I'd like the find the final constructor which would get called to apply the aspect on.

Comment: Consider looking at [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) or [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/roslyn). Cecil operates on the compiled assembly, like Reflection, but it has higher-level libraries built on top of it to support refactorings in the SharpDevelop IDE, so it might have something to make this easier. Roslyn operates on source code and gives you an object model based on that, so if you're willing to work against the source instead of binaries, it might be even easier.

Comment: @JoeWhite You mind posting that as an answer? I've given up [on mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9849028/590790). Too many holes and no guarantee it would work. Cecil or Roslyn is most likely a better approach, thank you for the tip!

Comment: I wasn't sure how well either would work, never having tried either for anything like this. But sure, I can make it an answer.

Comment: This information is not shown in the Object Browser of Visual Studio, either. As an example, type `System.Net.HttpListenerBasicIdentity` in VS and hit F12 to go to the metadata definition. You see [one public instance constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerbasicidentity.httplistenerbasicidentity.aspx). This is in the `System.dll` assembly. Clicking on the base class and hitting F12 again takes you to the `GenericIdentity` class. This is in a distinct assembly, `mscorlib.dll`. And `GenericIdentity` has no public or protected parameterless constructor (cont.)

Comment: (... continued) We can conclude that the visible constructor of `HttpListenerBasicIdentity` either chains the `base(string)` or `base(string, string)` constructor, or chains `this(...)` for some unseen (`private` or `internal`) instance constructor of `HttpListenerBasicIdentity`. Inspecting the IL we see that it actually chains `base(string, string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider looking at [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) or [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/roslyn).

Cecil operates on the compiled assembly, like Reflection does. it has higher-level libraries built on top of it to support refactorings in the SharpDevelop IDE, so it might have something to make this easier.

Roslyn operates on source code and gives you an object model based on that, so if you're willing to work against the source instead of binaries, it might be even easier to work with.

(I've never actually used Cecil for anything like this and I've never used Roslyn at all, so I can't do much more than point you at the projects and wish you luck. If you do manage to get something working, I'd be interested to hear how it went!)

Comment: I've accepted this answer as it's probably a better approach than the one I posted. A word of warning though, **I haven't gotten around to trying it yet!**

Answer (score 3):

This is a temporary answer, to state what I found so far.

I didn't find any property of `ConstructorInfo` which could indicate whether the constructor calls another constructor or not. Neither did the properties of [`MethodBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody.aspx).

I am having somewhat success evaluating the MSIL byte code. My first findings indicate the constructor which is eventually called starts out with `OpCodes.Call` immediately, except for a few possible other `OpCodes`. Constructors which call other constructors have 'unexpected' `OpCodes`.

```
public static bool CallsOtherConstructor( this ConstructorInfo constructor )
{
    MethodBody body = constructor.GetMethodBody();
    if ( body == null )
    {
        throw new ArgumentException( "Constructors are expected to always contain byte code." );
    }

    // Constructors at the end of the invocation chain start with 'call' immediately.
    var untilCall = body.GetILAsByteArray().TakeWhile( b => b != OpCodes.Call.Value );
    return !untilCall.All( b =>
        b == OpCodes.Nop.Value ||     // Never encountered, but my intuition tells me a no-op would be valid.
        b == OpCodes.Ldarg_0.Value || // Seems to always precede Call immediately.
        b == OpCodes.Ldarg_1.Value    // Seems to be added when calling base constructor.
        );
}
```

I'm not sure at all about MSIL. Perhaps it's impossible to have no-ops in between there, or there is no need at all to start out a constructor like that, but for all my current unit tests it seems to work.

```
[TestClass]
public class ConstructorInfoExtensionsTest
{
    class PublicConstructors
    {
        // First
        public PublicConstructors() : this( true ) {}

        // Second
        public PublicConstructors( bool one ) : this( true, true ) {}

        // Final
        public PublicConstructors( bool one, bool two ) {}

        // Alternate final
        public PublicConstructors( bool one, bool two, bool three ) {}
    }

    class PrivateConstructors
    {
        // First
        PrivateConstructors() : this( true ) {}

        // Second
        PrivateConstructors( bool one ) : this( true, true ) {}

        // Final
        PrivateConstructors( bool one, bool two ) {}

        // Alternate final
        PrivateConstructors( bool one, bool two, bool three ) {}
    }

    class TripleBaseConstructors : DoubleBaseConstructors
    {
        public TripleBaseConstructors() : base() { }
        public TripleBaseConstructors( bool one ) : base( one ) { }
    }

    class DoubleBaseConstructors : BaseConstructors
    {
        public DoubleBaseConstructors() : base() {}
        public DoubleBaseConstructors( bool one ) : base( one ) {}
    }

    class BaseConstructors : Base
    {
        public BaseConstructors() : base() {}
        public BaseConstructors( bool one ) : base( one ) {}
    }

    class Base
    {
        // No parameters
        public Base() {}

        // One parameter
        public Base( bool one ) {} 
    }

    class ContentConstructor
    {
        public ContentConstructor()
        {
            SomeMethod();
        }

        public ContentConstructor( bool one )
        {
            int bleh = 0;
        }

        bool setTwo;
        public ContentConstructor( bool one, bool two )
        {
            setTwo = two;
        }

        void SomeMethod() {}
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CallsOtherConstructorTest()
    {           
        Action<ConstructorInfo[]> checkConstructors = cs =>
        {
            ConstructorInfo first = cs.Where( c => c.GetParameters().Count() == 0 ).First();
            Assert.IsTrue( first.CallsOtherConstructor() );
            ConstructorInfo second = cs.Where( c => c.GetParameters().Count() == 1 ).First();
            Assert.IsTrue( second.CallsOtherConstructor() );
            ConstructorInfo final = cs.Where( c => c.GetParameters().Count() == 2 ).First();
            Assert.IsFalse( final.CallsOtherConstructor() );
            ConstructorInfo alternateFinal = cs.Where( c => c.GetParameters().Count() == 3 ).First();
            Assert.IsFalse( alternateFinal.CallsOtherConstructor() );
        };

        // Public and private constructors.
        checkConstructors( typeof( PublicConstructors ).GetConstructors() );
        checkConstructors( typeof( PrivateConstructors ).GetConstructors( BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance ) );

        // Inheritance.
        Action<ConstructorInfo[]> checkBaseConstructors = cs =>
        {
            ConstructorInfo noParameters = cs.Where( c => c.GetParameters().Count() == 0 ).First();
            ConstructorInfo oneParameter = cs.Where( c => c.GetParameters().Count() == 1 ).First();

            // Only interested in constructors specified on this type, not base constructors,
            // thus calling a base constructor shouldn't qualify as 'true'.
            Assert.IsFalse( noParameters.CallsOtherConstructor() );
            Assert.IsFalse( oneParameter.CallsOtherConstructor() );
        };
        checkBaseConstructors( typeof( BaseConstructors ).GetConstructors() );
        checkBaseConstructors( typeof( DoubleBaseConstructors ).GetConstructors() );
        checkBaseConstructors( typeof( TripleBaseConstructors ).GetConstructors() );

        // Constructor with content.
        foreach( var constructor in typeof( ContentConstructor ).GetConstructors() )
        {
            Assert.IsFalse( constructor.CallsOtherConstructor() );
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: A useful resource of [all the byte codes can be found here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bluecollar/archive/2006/09/27/773065.aspx).

Comment: Constructors which call base constructors seem to to have a `OpCodes.Ldarg_1` value after `OpCodes.Ldarg_0`.

Comment: The updated version doesn't seem to work for inner class constructors yet.

Comment: It appears that the byte preceding the RET will be `Ldloc_0` if a constructor calls an inner ctor and `Stloc_0` if it doesn't call anything. Haven't checked for a call to a base ctor.

Comment: I am sorry to break it to you, but it appears that your code is anything but right, although I appreciate your effort, as 1) a ctor will always call another ctor or base ctor (unless it's a struct and the ctor doesn't explicitly call another ctor or it's System.Object), and 2) Ldarg_1/Ldarg0 etc have nothing to do with a base ctor or not, you have to actually check the operand and determine the method called to see if it's a base ctor or not

Comment: Ldarg_1 represents the first arg passed, Ldarg_2 to the second etc., and Ldarg_0 refers to the `this` pointer, nothing about `base` ctor vs `this` ctor

Comment: @annakata Ldloc_0 loads the first local variable on the stack while Stloc_0 saves the first value on the stack in the first local variable, nothing with the called method, to check which method is called you actually have to check the operand

Comment: Rereading this now, it seems that when I wrote this I knew it was anything but "right".  seems more like an exploration, which is why I must have given up going further down that path and accepted the Roslyn answer. Thank you for the additional context!

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is to add a property to the object telling the aspect was applied. So, you won't be applying the aspect several times as you can check that property. It's not what you asked but it may help you with your underlying issue.

Comment: That wouldn't guarantee that the aspect code would be executed for every possible constructor invocation. Unless you are implying the code I add to _every_ constructor is aware of a property which causes it to only be executed once? That might work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot check or inspect code using reflection in an easy fashion. All reflection lets you do is reflect on the metadata information of the assembly.

You can use [GetMethodBody](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody.aspx) to grab the content of the method, but then you will have to actually parse it and understand the IL yourself.